# Is os kernel event-based? Does the kernel multithreaded or multiprocess?

Tags: operating-system, kernel

I have read some books about os kernel recently. I knew that when an event (like clock ticks) happens, it will trigger an interruption then the kernel's specified routine response.

So my questions are:
1)When an interruption was triggered and its corresponding kernel routine was still running, then another interruption was triggered for some sort of reason. How will the kernel response? Will it mask the second interruption when it was handling the first interruption? Or the first interruption's corresponding routine was interrupted by the second one? If the second condition was true, how the kernel make sure the routines are "reentrance"?

2)Does the kernel multithreaded or multiprocess? I mean when things go like the first question, the kernel will use CPU's extra cores to handle interruptions? If it did, how can the kernel make sure everything works correctly just like running on a single-core CPU?

Comment: **Too many questions** in the single question post. Also, every specific OS kernel has its own way for handling interrupts and multithreaded/multiprocess aspects. Asking about these aspects for OS kernel *in genera*l has a little sense: every answer would be "it depends".

Comment: Yeah.. the OS designers/deelopers/testers/debuggers ensure that it all works on the target hardware.  This is why OS development is non-trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) If an interruption is triggered and its corresponding kernel routine is still running, then another interruption is triggered for some sort of reason; how will the kernel respond? Will it mask the second interruption when it was handling the first interruption? Or the first interruption's corresponding routine was interrupted by the second one?

Yes; different operating systems may either:

- mask other IRQs while an IRQ is being handled
- allow different IRQs to nest (interrupt each other)
- allow all IRQs to nest (including the same IRQ interrupting itself)
- mask some IRQs and allow other IRQs to nest
- not use more than one IRQs (e.g. only use a timer IRQ, and poll everything else)

> If the second condition was true, how does the kernel make sure the routines are "reentrant"?

If the OS designer decided that (some or all) IRQs may interrupt others; then they'll need to figure out how reentrancy will work for whatever cases they allowed. This can be "do nothing that causes a problem" (e.g. maybe IRQ handler just sends a notification to a task that does the real work later), and could be further restrictions (e.g. temporarily acquire a lock that prevents further IRQs for pieces of the IRQ handler that might cause a reentrancy problem but not other pieces that don't).

> 2) Does the kernel multithreaded or multiprocess? I mean when things go like the first question, the kernel will use CPU's extra cores to handle interruptions?

Yes; different operating systems may either use multi-threading or multi-processing (or both or neither); and may or may not use other cores to handle interrupts.

> If it did, how can the kernel make sure everything works correctly just like running on a single-core CPU?

If a kernel does use other cores to handle interrupts; it will also do something to ensure everything works correctly. "Something" could be a system of locks, or transaction memory, or lock-free/block-free algorithms, or a "shared nothing" approach, or a combination of these things.